# How do I install Windows Codepack API into Visual C# 2010 express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Ok, it seems everyone else knows this since I can't find it on the internet. I want to use the Windows Codepack API, and I have no idea how to use it with Visual C# 2010, can anyone explain this for me? I've downloaded and extracted them, and found the dlls, I just don't know where to put the dlls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the DLLs anywhere in your disk, then right-click your project, click Add Reference, and select them from the Browse tab.